# Nested Query for multiple schemas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

I have two schema :  User  and  Request

In the request schema I basically have fields like eventId, userId, status etc.

In user schema theres ofcourse information about the user including userId, firstname, lastname etc.

**What I wish to do is retrieve the top 5 user information with the most request marked as complete.**

So I first tried querying in for the request schema whose status: complete

From that filtered request i guess I have to count the number of duplicate userId and return the Top 5 userId.

Last step should be using that userId to fetch the user information from the user schema.

I got the first query but I am unable to come up with a query for the rest.

Heres an example

***User Schema:***

```
   _id
   firstName
   lastName
```

***Request Schema***

```
 _id
 userId
 ownerId
 status
```

So everytime a user creates a request, the userId is filled in with users Id.

Say user1 has 200 requests whose status = complete, 
user 2 has 100
user 3 has 50
user 4 has 25
user 5 has 10
user 6 has 5

I want to print the first name and last name of the user with the top 5 completed request,

In this case it should be user 1, user 2, user 3, user 4, user, 5 in order.

Comment: Could you show some sample documents and the query you're trying to run on it ?

Comment: I've updated the schema could you have a look please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done using MongoDB [Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)

```js
db.requests.aggregate([
  {
    $group: { // group the same users together, count the requests
      _id: '$userId', count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  }, 
  {
    $lookup: { // "join" the previous results with the user documents
      from: 'users',localField: 'userId', foreignField: '_id', as: 'user' }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: '$user' // unwind the previous results, which is an array
  },
  {
    $sort: { count: -1 } // sort by count field descending
  }
])
```

Your result will look like this

```js
[
  { _id: 'user1_id', count: 200, user: { /* user1 document */ } },
  { _id: 'user2_id', count: 100, user: { /* user2 document */ } },
  /* ... */
]
```